# unable to fill the div element height to fit screen?

Tags: html, css

i tried a lot, but can't make the div to fit the screen when i zoom in the browser by ctrl+'-' , don't know why height:100% in style to div.style doesn't work

```css
div.left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="left" id="left_panel">
  hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are default browser specific styles. You need to override default browser styles.

```
html, body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the snippet please.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0,
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="left" id="left_panel">
  hello
</div>
```